# Generating DDL statements of database from Google Cloud Sql using eclipse cause issue in script?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, google-cloud-sql

I connected to a Google Cloud SQL database from eclipse using Data Source explorer. But when I generate DDL of that database using its option `Generate DDL`, I can't get the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in my script but get the corresponding primary key.

How would i go about getting the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in my script?

Comment: Are you using the Google Plugin for Eclipse?

Comment: @ Neil H, yes i'm using Google Plugin

Comment: I suggest that you reread your question and try to phrase it differently so that it is clearer what you are asking otherwise people will vote to close it as Not A Question. You just need to add a couple of more sentences instead of trying to explain everything in one sentence (the second one).

Comment: surely the primary key should be an auto increment as it should be the id of the row? (for all your tables) ++ could you give an example of what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not directly answering the question, I believe it will provide a solution to the root goal:  Extracting the DDL.

Assumption: The following is a shell script, so an appropriate environment (OS X, Linux, cygwin) is required

Steps:

1. Install the command line scripts ([follow the instructions here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/commandline))
2. Create the following custom script in the same directory as the google_sql.sh:

   ```
   GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE=test:test

   echo "SELECT CONCAT('SELECT CONCAT(\"SHOW CREATE TABLE ',schema_name,'.\",table_name,\";\") \"select \\\\\"use ',schema_name,';\\\\\";\" FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = \"',schema_name,'\";') 'use information_schema;' FROM SCHEMATA WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema');" >> $$.1.get_schema.sql

   ./google_sql.sh $GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE information_schema < $$.1.get_schema.sql > $$.2.show_create.sql

   ./google_sql.sh $GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE information_schema < $$.2.show_create.sql > $$.3.sql.out

   ./google_sql.sh $GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE information_schema < $$.3.sql.out > $$.4.create.raw

   awk -F"  " '/Table Create Table/{print "";}
    /CREATE/{sub(/^..*CREATE TABLE/,"CREATE TABLE");print $0}
    $1 == "" {print $0}
    /^\)/{print $0";"}
    /^use/{print $0}' $$.4.create.raw > $GOOGLE_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE.ddl.sql

   rm $$.*
   ```
3. Replace "test:test" in the script with your Google Cloud instance identifier
4. Execute the script to produce a file of the format "test:test".ddl.sql which will have the DDL for all tables in all databases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

[Google Cloud SQL Step 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Create_your_database_and_table)

Another example of using DDL is this:

```
CREATE TABLE tabelle
(
feld datentyp [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value] [AUTO_INCREMENT] [COMMENT 'string'],
CONSTRAINT name
  PRIMARY KEY (feld1, feld2, ...)
  FOREIGN KEY (feld1, feld2, ...) REFERENCES tabelle (feld1, feld2)
)
```

Source: http://www.tinohempel.de/info/info/datenbank/sql_tabelle.htm
It's in German but the examples are very good!

Hope I understood your question right and this helps!